# Why is "alike" not possible in this sentence? (Choosing from: alike, similar to, exactly and just as)

Tags: word-choice

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, __ (?) __  journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

In that sentence I was supposed to choose the right answer from these options:
*alike*, *similar to*, *exactly* and *just as*. The answer is *just as*. Can you explain to me why the option *alike* is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing two predicates (has quills....has needles)  we use "as".

**A porcupine has quills just as a cactus has needles.**

When we wish to say two nouns (e.g. cactus, porcupine) share a feature, we say they are *similar to* each other or that they are *alike*.

**The cactus is *similar to* the porcupine.**

**The cactus and the porcupine *are alike*.**

The expression *exactly the same* means that something is identical to something else.

**I have been stuck by a porcupine, and I have been stuck by a cactus. The pain was *exactly the same*.**

Answer (score 1):

Alike is an adjective.  What you need here is a conjunction.  "Just as" is effectively a conjugation.

Comment: "Alike" can be an adjective or an adverb.  In neither form is does it work in this sentence. If one joined the sentences with "just as," then "as" would be a conjunction, modified with the adverb "just."

Comment: @Adam - What you say is true, but if _alike_ were in this sentence, it would function as an adjective (_alike journalists_).

Answer (score 1):

### Just As

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **just as** journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

If one joined the sentences with *"just as,"* then *"as"* would be a conjunction, modified with the adverb *"just."*  This is an efficient, natural way to express this.  Note that this is comparing the *idea* of need for an eye with the *idea* of need for a nose.

### Similar to

*Similar* can be made to work in a couple of ways

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **similar to** journalists, who must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

Here, we are comparing photographers with journalists.  Photographers are similar to journalists.  Additional verbiage specifies how.

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news; **Similarly,** journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

Now we are using the adverbial form, similarly, and we are again comparing the existence of two needs, rather than comparing photographers vs. journalists directly.

### Exactly

*Exactly* can be an adverb modifying *as* (See the first example, with *just*.)

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **exactly as** journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story

This is grammatical, but doesn't sound as smooth *to me* as using *just* did.

### Alike

*"Alike"* can be an adjective or an adverb. In neither form is does it work well in this sentence.   In dated English, you might see:

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **alike as** journalists, who must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

...but this sounds biblical and weird in this context.  I *think* it is grammatical, but it is far from idiomatic.

### Just like

J.R. points out in the comments that *just like* can be used also.  The totally non-controversial way would be like this:

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **just like** journalists, who must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

*Like* is a preposition, *just* is an adverb.

Another option exists:

> Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **just like** journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story.

Here *like* is being used as a conjunction.  This is [not its historical function](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-as), and many people consider it wrong.  I avoid using *like* as a conjunction, but I am including it because one does hear/see this construction frequently, at least in the U.S.

Comment: If anyone can correct me or assure me on the historical (grammatical?) usage of _alike,_ please do!

Comment: I agree that _alike as_ sounds weird here, but _just like_ could work: _Good press photographers must have an ‘eye’ for news, **just like** journalists must have a ‘nose’ for a good story_.